# Playing a video stored on EC2 instance from Android app using VideoView?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-ec2

Hey so I have an mp4 file stored on a Amazon EC2 instance. It is called test.mp4 . It is stored in the location /home/ec2-user/testApp/test.mp4

So I have a public dns name for the server so what will the url of the video be? When I call setVideoUrl("")?

Thanks guys.

Comment: hey did you ever figure out how to do this because i am having the same issue! Thank! :)

Answer (score 2):

You would have to install a web server like Apache first on this instance and place the file in the according web directory, e.g. "/var/www/".
Then you can access the file using the URL to your EC2 instance combined with the relative path to the video file in the web directory.

Or you would have to create a web service which accesses this file and deploy it on your EC2 instance.

Comment: Does this work? Do i have to have the videos in the "/var/www/"? I am having the same issue :/

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to setting up your own web server you could put the video on S3 and stream it from there. There are several tutorials available, from Amazon and others, outlining this approach:

- http://www.miracletutorials.com/s3-streaming-video-with-cloudfront/
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html